# Swift, How to make an Array of UIBezierPaths?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibezierpath

I can make 1 just fine, and in Objective-C I would just slap a "[10]" on my first declaration and be good to go. But swift arrays are so foreign to me, I don't understand at all. I need a 10x10 grid of squares *(UIBezierPaths)* Iv tried looking at many posts but I can't understand. Could someone please help out and explain the nature of swift arrays, am I missing something?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
var paths: [[UIBezierPath]] = [[UIBezierPath]]()

for index in 0 ... 9 {
    paths.append([UIBezierPath]())
    for kdx in 0 ... 19 {
        paths[index].append(UIBezierPath())
    }
}
```

Creates a 2d array of `UIBezierPath` and then iterates over two loops. In the first loop we add a new list of paths and in the second loop we add new paths to these lists.

For a single list of paths just use the inner loop.

```
var paths: [UIBezierPath] = [UIBezierPath]()
for kdx in 0 ... 9 {
    paths.append(UIBezierPath())
}
```

Comment: Yes that helps a lot, I find swifts arrays more confusing than Objective-C but thats okay. Thanks so much